# Blender 2.82 won't let me add reference images

Tags: image, model, blender, modeling

### I've used blender before, but it has been a while, and man has it gone through some changes. Anyways, to the point:

I am trying to upload a reference image so I may model around it, as to have an accurate model of my character. I've tried searching in Blender for the reference images I'll need, I've tried dragging and dropping it in, I've tried importing my image, nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas? I use Blender 2.82.

Answer (score 0):

Just press Shift+A and select Image > Reference image or Image > Background Image
(Whichever suits you, I prefer the bkground image)